# django is there a way to annotate nested object?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have the following situation. I have three models, Post, User and Friends.

```
class User(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Friend(models.Model):
   user1 = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='my_friends1')
   user2 = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='my_friends2')

class Post(models.Model):
   subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Every time I bring users, I want to bring the number of his friends:

```
User.objects.filter(name__startswith='Joe').annotate(fc=Count('my_friends1'))
```

This works fine.

However, I want to make this work when I bring the users as nested objects of Post. I'm using there select_related to minimized DB calls, so I want to do something like:

```
Post.objects.filter(subject='sport').select_related('user').annotate(user__fc=Count('user__my_friends1'))
```

However, this creates field user__fc under post, and not field fc under `post.user`.
Is there a way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: I can think of many reasons you might want this, but it might help to know from you... Why do you need the information to exist on your instance as "post.user.fc" instead of as "post.user__fc" ?  Knowing why might suggest which direction you want to go with hacking this in.  "Hacking" it in is probably what will be necessary, I don't think that customizing the "related manager" is going to help in this situation. But, I can think of several ways you might hack this in with minimal ugliness.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `Prefetch` class:

```py
from django.db.models import Count, Prefetch

posts = Post.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch('user', User.objects.annotate(fc=Count('my_friends1'))))

for post in posts:
    print(post.subject)
    print(post.user.fc)
```

NB : this does two database queries (Django does the join between Post and User in this case) :

```
'SELECT "myapp_post"."id", "myapp_post"."subject", "myapp_post"."user_id" FROM "myapp_post"


'SELECT "myapp_user"."id", "myapp_user"."password", "myapp_user"."last_login", "myapp_user"."is_superuser", "myapp_user"."username", "myapp_user"."first_name", "myapp_user"."last_name", "myapp_user"."email", "myapp_user"."is_staff", "myapp_user"."is_active", "myapp_user"."date_joined", COUNT("myapp_friend"."id") AS "fc" FROM "myapp_user" LEFT OUTER JOIN "myapp_friend" ON ("myapp_user"."id" = "myapp_friend"."user1_id") WHERE "myapp_user"."id" IN (3, 4) GROUP BY "myapp_user"."id", "myapp_user"."password", "myapp_user"."last_login", "myapp_user"."is_superuser", "myapp_user"."username", "myapp_user"."first_name", "myapp_user"."last_name", "myapp_user"."email", "myapp_user"."is_staff", "myapp_user"."is_active", "myapp_user"."date_joined"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom manger for your models, as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset) and then override its `get_queryset()` method to add the custom column to your model upon query.

In order to use this manager for a reverse relation, you should set the base manager as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#using-managers-for-related-object-access).

Another approach would be something like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#using-a-custom-reverse-manager), which you specify the manager of the related model with a hard-coded attribute.